# Unity Substances dipslay light in reverse

Tags: unity-game-engine

3d object in my last project do not work as i planed. To thing is, when i add point light which settings are here:

[image]

to the scene the sphere is illuminated the way i want. And here is how it looks like:

[image]

the main issue starts when i add the substance to the sphere and somehow my 3d-object is lighted from the other site. Here is how it looks like

[image]

The thing that bothers me is that when i create a new project evrything works the way is should.

So i thought that the problem is connected with light so i reset the lightning settings by 
window -> lightining -> settings -> right click in right top corner-> reset

but it does nothing at all.

Any idea what i could have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So everthing is connected to build settings. In the not working one "Android" build option is choosen and in the working one "PC MAC LINUX" option is choosen.

Comment: @TJWolschon
 Allegorithmic says that Androind build is just not supported right now. The thing is that if You do not have any knowledge connected to the subject, as far as i concern. You should not remark my answer as funny and unrelated. The switch of bulid helps with this problem You can check it, before downvoting or insulting me.